# Setting timestamp inside transaction

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transactions

We have the following two repeatedly and independently running tasks on our database (PostgreSQL):

Session 1 does some updates in a transaction and set the timestamp of the updated datasets:

```
BEGIN;
...
UPDATE table SET ..., timestamp = current_timestamp WHERE ...;
... // (A)
COMMIT;
```

Session 2 selects all datasets that were updated since its last run:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN last_run AND current_timestamp;
last_run = current_timestamp;
...
```

If session 2 starts while session 1 is at (A) it will not see the changes because the timestamp will not be set until the commit but to an earlier value.
Furthermore no subsequent session 2 will select the changes because last_run will already be greater than the timestamp.
So the problem is that session 1 sets the timestamp to a wrong value respectively at a wrong time and thus changes may be "forgotten".

A possible workaround would be to store the updated datasets ids in another table in session 1 and select and delete them from this table in session 2.
But perhaps someone has a better idea...

Comment: Do you want a mechanism to allow both to run concurrently?  If so, the exact code and business logic is needed.  More commonly, you would treat each transaction block as a fixed unit, when one process is within the block, no other process can start the block.  This directly avoids "but what if one has started but not finished" problem.  It is achieved by using table/row locks.  Do you know which you prefer?

Comment: It must be possible to run them concurrently. The code is rather big so I can't post it but task 1 basically imports data and task 2 exports the changes. The exporter must run every 30 minutes and can not wait for a possible import. The importer runs more often but for a short time and can not wait for the exporter that runs for about 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This sort of question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914675/reading-only-new-rows-from-a-log-like-table-in-a-database) comes up from time to time-- as far as I can tell, the only completely reliable way is to do what you've described, store updated IDs in some table in the first process and mark them as processed in the second. Basically this is reinventing a message-queue in the database. You've described quite well how a naive solution will miss updates.

Having the import process mark updated rows can be done quite easily, or even implemented using triggers on your data table. If you only have one consumer process, then all it has to do is `delete from updated_item returning item_id` to get a list of updates. It sounds like it's a lot more complicated but IMHO it isn't, really. Features like being able to monitor how big the backlog is emerge for free, too.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to avoid selecting rows that might be in contention.  Select rows between last_run and current_timestamp - interval '1' minute.  Exactly how much time you think you should buffer is something you'd have to decide based on the volume of transactions, and how long it takes for the update transaction to complete.  Just make sure that you also set last_run = current_timestamp - interval '1' minute, and you should not have any problems with lost rows that were not committed just before your SELECT began.

Comment: We thought about something similar. But finding the best interval is difficult because we have both very short and very long running updates.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO session2 must `select where zetimestamp > lastrun`, and set last_run to `MAX(timestamp of processed_items)`. Sessions that were running, but had uncommitted data during the run of session2 will have timestamps *before* session2, and would be hidden for subsequent runs of session2 if you would set last_run to current_timestamp.

Besides: in most cases, usage of current_timestamp is unwanted. *Natural* timestamps cannot have a value greater than current_timestamp, so every existing timestamp will be <= current_timestamp, and comparing to it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

**current_timestamp** returns the start time of the current transaction, not the current clock time. Check [clock_timestamp()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT), that will change within the current transaction.

Comment: True. But it would still be earlier than the commit.

Comment: That is why my solution does work. MAX(something in the past) is always before the current_timestamp=time_used_at_commit.