# how to get last Postresql serial ID that all rows before it are committed?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgresql 9.0.5 and I have a cron job that periodically reads newly created rows from a table and accumulate its value into a summary table that has hourly data.

I need to get the latest ID (serial) that is committed and all rows before it are committed.

The currval function will not give a correct value in this case, because the transaction inserting currval may commit earlier than others. Using SELECT statement at a moment, I can see Id column is not continuous because some rows are still not committed.

```
Here is some sample code I have used to test:
--test race condition
create table mydata(id serial,val int);

--run in thread 1
create or replace function insert_delay() returns void as $$
begin
insert into mydata(val) values (1);
perform pg_sleep(60);
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

--run in thread 2
create or replace function insert_ok() returns void as $$
begin
insert into mydata(val) values (2);
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

--run in thread 3
mytest=# select * from mydata;  --SHOULD HAVE SEEN id = 1 and 2;
 id | val
----+-----
  2 |   2
(1 row)
```

I even tried some statement like the one below;

```
select max(id) from mydata age(xmin) >= age(txid_snapshot_xmin(txid_current_snapshot())::text::xid);
```

But in production line (running high volume transactions), the returned max(id) will not move forwards (even all the busy transaction are finished). So this does not work either.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't let a trigger build the summary table in realtime?

Comment: 1. I would do this with a timestamp column. 2. I haven't understood entirely what you want to do, but in case you haven't seen it: you can control the read level with the transaction isolation: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html so you could possibly "see" the other, non-committed transaction

Comment: this is basically the same problem (although asking from a different angle) as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9226322/setting-timestamp-inside-transaction/9226786 which itself is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914675/reading-only-new-rows-from-a-log-like-table-in-a-database, which see.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a really good way to do this directly.  I think the best option really is to create a temporary table which truncates on transaction commit, and a trigger that inserts such into that table.  Then you can look up the values from the temp table.